# Component is making buzzing noise

Tags: components, identification

What kind of components are those two at the left? What's their purpose?
The one of the right has been making a "buzzing" noise for the past couple of weeks. Why is that?

￼[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Left looks like a relay based on the symbols drawn on it. The right looks like a transformer of sorts but I can't confirm on that one. I do know transformers have a tendency to buzz when broken.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. Side-view of BBC B1028.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Top-view of BBC B1028. This seems to be a panel-mount variation. The OP photo shows a DIN mount.*

This is a relay or contactor for 1 or 3-phase switching.

> The one of the right has been making a "buzzing" noise for the past couple of weeks. Why is that?

The relay uses an electro-magnetic solenoid to move the contacts against the opposing spring force. When the moving armature contacts the coil core there can often be a bit of mechanical vibration. Sometimes a thump can fix it but it will probably return at next switch on.

Comment: +1: "Sometimes a thump can fix it..." Perhaps the best troubleshooting advice ever :)

Comment: How to deal with an annoying partner? Will the same idea work? Is there any risk involved lol?

Answer (score 3):

A low level of buzzing might be normal. A more noticeable buzzing that has suddenly appeared after an extended time of use is likely the sign of a problem. The cause of the problem could be mechanical wear. It could be corrosion or foreign material in the relay. A tiny metal particle may have broken off and worked its way to a position where it prevents the armature from closing firmly against the core. It is even possible that some foreign material has been in the relay since manufacture, or some other manufacturing defect has allowed a component to get slightly loose. Whatever the case you need to consider the possibility that the relay may be near failure, and weigh the cost of replacement against the cost of unexpected failure. It might be possible to repair the relay, but that is probably not the best economical alternative.